# How do I stop Google Charts creating two SVG's for a single chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

This is my first time posting a question on Stack Overflow (I hope I'm doing it right).
I'm having trouble with the Google Timeline chart as it is creating  a second SVG element in the mark up. I want to target the SVG however it looks like the contents of it are sometimes spread over two SVG elements. I have managed to replicate the issue  using one of Google's examples, three data rows works fine (a single SVG element is created);however, if it has more than three rows it creates a second SVG element. 
Is this something I can change?

Thank you

This code will create two SVG elements in the markup (I only want one).

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
                 dataTable.addRows([

          [ 'Adams8',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Washington9', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Adams10',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],         
          [ 'Jefferson11',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

        chart.draw(dataTable);
      }
```

This is what the markup looks like when two SVG elements are created

```
<div id="timeline" style="height: 180px;">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div style="position: relative; width: 793px; height: 180px;" dir="ltr">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        (First SVG)        <svg width="793" height="180" style="overflow: hidden;" aria-label="A chart.">
                    <defs id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0"></defs>
                    <g>
                        <text text-anchor="middle" x="124.87524076192885" y="151.05" font-family="Arial" font-size="13" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">1790</text>
                        <text text-anchor="middle" x="464.5278076434366" y="151.05" font-family="Arial" font-size="13" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">1800</text>
                    </g>
                    <g></g>
                    <g></g>
                </svg>
                <div style="height: 130px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; width: 793px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
              ( Second SVG)     <svg width="793" height="163.968" style="overflow: hidden;" aria-label="A chart.">
                        <defs id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_1"></defs>
                        <g>
                            <rect x="0" y="0" width="793" height="40.992" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
                            <path d="M102,0L102,40.992" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <path d="M124.87524076192885,0L124.87524076192885,40.992" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <path d="M464.5278076434366,0L464.5278076434366,40.992" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <rect x="0" y="40.992" width="793" height="40.992" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#e6e6e6"></rect>
                            <path d="M102,40.992L102,81.984" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <path d="M124.87524076192885,40.992L124.87524076192885,81.984" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <path d="M464.5278076434366,40.992L464.5278076434366,81.984" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <rect x="0" y="81.984" width="793" height="40.992" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
                            <path d="M102,81.984L102,122.976" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <path d="M124.87524076192885,81.984L124.87524076192885,122.976" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <path d="M464.5278076434366,81.984L464.5278076434366,122.976" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <rect x="0" y="122.976" width="793" height="40.992" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#e6e6e6"></rect>
                            <path d="M102,122.976L102,163.968" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <path d="M124.87524076192885,122.976L124.87524076192885,163.968" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <path d="M464.5278076434366,122.976L464.5278076434366,163.968" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <path d="M0,40.992L793,40.992" stroke="#b7b7b7" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <path d="M0,81.984L793,81.984" stroke="#b7b7b7" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <path d="M0,122.976L793,122.976" stroke="#b7b7b7" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                            <text text-anchor="end" x="89" y="25.046" font-family="Arial" font-size="13" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#4d4d4d">Adams8</text>
                            <text text-anchor="end" x="89" y="66.038" font-family="Arial" font-size="13" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#4d4d4d">Washington9</text>
                            <text text-anchor="end" x="89" y="107.02999999999999" font-family="Arial" font-size="13" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#4d4d4d">Adams10</text>
                            <text text-anchor="end" x="89" y="148.02200000000002" font-family="Arial" font-size="13" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#4d4d4d">Jefferson11</text>
                            <rect x="0" y="0" width="793" height="163.968" stroke="#9a9a9a" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></rect>
                        </g>
                        <g></g>
                        <g>
                            <rect x="368.45412155674506" y="9" width="135.78662312349434" height="22.991999999999997" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#4285f4"></rect>
                            <rect x="103" y="49.992" width="265.45412155674506" height="22.991999999999997" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#db4437"></rect>
                            <rect x="368.45412155674506" y="90.984" width="135.78662312349434" height="22.991999999999997" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f4b400"></rect>
                            <rect x="504.2407446802394" y="131.976" width="271.7592553197606" height="22.991999999999997" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0f9d58"></rect>
                        </g>
                        <g></g>
                        <g></g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 190px; left: 803px; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px;" aria-hidden="true">1790</div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code works fine, it just has one less data row and it only creates a single SVG element.

```
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
                 dataTable.addRows([

          [ 'Adams8',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Washington9', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],      
          [ 'Jefferson11',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

        chart.draw(dataTable);
      }
```

This is how the markup looks when I have three rows. I would like the markup to always regardless of the number of rows (one SVG element)

```
<div id="timeline" style="height: 180px;">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div style="position: relative; width: 793px; height: 180px;" dir="ltr">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
         (Just the one SVG) <svg width="793" height="180" style="overflow: hidden;" aria-label="A chart.">
                    <defs id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0"></defs>
                    <g>
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="793" height="40.992" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
                        <path d="M102,0L102,40.992" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                        <path d="M125.45221270993002,0L125.45221270993002,40.992" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                        <path d="M473.67168409735115,0L473.67168409735115,40.992" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                        <rect x="0" y="40.992" width="793" height="40.992" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#e6e6e6"></rect>
                        <path d="M102,40.992L102,81.984" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                        <path d="M125.45221270993002,40.992L125.45221270993002,81.984" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                        <path d="M473.67168409735115,40.992L473.67168409735115,81.984" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                        <rect x="0" y="81.984" width="793" height="40.992" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
                        <path d="M102,81.984L102,122.976" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                        <path d="M125.45221270993002,81.984L125.45221270993002,122.976" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                        <path d="M473.67168409735115,81.984L473.67168409735115,122.976" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                        <path d="M0,40.992L793,40.992" stroke="#b7b7b7" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                        <path d="M0,81.984L793,81.984" stroke="#b7b7b7" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
                        <text text-anchor="end" x="89" y="25.046" font-family="Arial" font-size="13" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#4d4d4d">Adams8</text>
                        <text text-anchor="end" x="89" y="66.038" font-family="Arial" font-size="13" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#4d4d4d">Washington9</text>
                        <text text-anchor="end" x="89" y="107.02999999999999" font-family="Arial" font-size="13" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#4d4d4d">Jefferson11</text>
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="793" height="122.976" stroke="#9a9a9a" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></rect>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <text text-anchor="middle" x="125.45221270993002" y="144.026" font-family="Arial" font-size="13" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">1790</text>
                        <text text-anchor="middle" x="473.67168409735115" y="144.026" font-family="Arial" font-size="13" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">1800</text>
                    </g>
                    <g></g>
                    <g>
                        <rect x="375.1747744743484" y="9" width="139.2115082764608" height="22.991999999999997" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#4285f4"></rect>
                        <rect x="103" y="49.992" width="272.1747744743484" height="22.991999999999997" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#db4437"></rect>
                        <rect x="514.3862827508092" y="90.984" width="278.6137172491908" height="22.991999999999997" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f4b400"></rect>
                    </g>
                    <g></g>
                    <g></g>
                    <g></g>
                    <g></g>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 190px; left: 803px; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px;" aria-hidden="true">1790</div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle for the example with two SVG elements. https://jsfiddle.net/twm5h1e7/3/

Fiddle for example with a single SVG element. https://jsfiddle.net/twm5h1e7/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the extra `<svg>` appears when the height of the chart cannot contain all of the rows.
the default height is only `200`.
the purpose is to allow the chart to be scrolled vertically,
while keeping the x-axis visible.

to prevent the second `<svg>`, set the `height` option to ensure all of the chart is visible.

```
chart.draw(dataTable, {
  height: (dataTable.getNumberOfRows() * 45) + 45
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'President'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Start'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'End'});
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Adams8', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Washington9', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
    ['Adams10', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Jefferson11', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)]
  ]);
  chart.draw(dataTable, {
    height: (dataTable.getNumberOfRows() * 45) + 45
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help WhiteHat, increasing the height did the trick.